# Custom cron job is not scheduling Magento2

Tags: php, linux, cron, magento2

I am trying to add cronjob through crontab.xml in my custom module, but they are not appearing in `cron_schedule` table after running `php bin/magento cron:run` many times. 
If i enter time as `<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>` it works and job get schedule in `cron_schedule` table. But i have to set time to run cronjob at 1:00 am. here is my `crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="abc_import" instance="Abc\Xyz\Model\Api" method="importProducts">
            <schedule>0 1 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

What about running cron like this?

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: have you told your servers crontab to run Magento cron all the time? https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-cron-job/